innodb_buffer_pool_size is not descreased
I use mysql 8.0.33 in docker.
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./store:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld.cnf

8 GB available RAM on server.
In my.cnf
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=6 # was 4
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=500M # was 1GB
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3GB # was 4GB

I restarted docker container with database twice.
I checked that the file exists inside container and contains my latest changes.
But when I checked in db by query
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size; # returns 524288000, expected
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_instances; # returns 6, expected
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size; # returns 6291456000, surprice

Documentation says

If you alter innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size, innodb_buffer_pool_size is automatically adjusted to a value that is equal to or a multiple of innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances.

But 524288000 * 6 = 3145728000
SHOW STATUS WHERE Variable_name='InnoDB_buffer_pool_resize_status';
SELECT variable_name, variable_value FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE LOWER(variable_name) LIKE "innodb_buffer_pool_resize%";

Returns zeros and blanks.
Docker stats shows 5.073GiB memory consumption.
How does mysql actually calculate `innodb_buffer_pool_size'?
Is it possible to set it to 3GB with 6 chunks by 500M?

This is because of auto alignment in pool size.
Possible ways:

remove innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size from my.cnf
set innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=134217728

So with pool_size=3GB and pool_instances=6, the chunk size would be 134217728(not 500M).
